# Compact embedding in $C^{k,2+\alpha}$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness, arzela-ascoli

Could anyone please help me understand the compact embedding of $C^{k,2+\alpha}$ space?

I am reading a paper about second order elliptic pde on $C^{k,2+\alpha}$ space. Here is the link of the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.6727.pdf. (page 55)
When it comes to the proof of the uniqueness of the solution it says:

> By applying the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, we can extract a subsequence, which we continue to denote by $\{ u_n\}_{n∈N}$, which converges in $C^{k,2+β} (\bar{\rm S})$, for all $β < α$, to a limit function $u\in C^{k,2+α} (\bar{\rm S})$
> as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Could anyone please give a proof of this?

Thank you so much. Appreciate your time and effort of reading my post.

Comment: I guess that $S$ is a bounded open set...?

Comment: I believe you also need some regularity on the set $S$ to get the compactness.

Comment: Yes, the domain is bounded.

Comment: I am confused by why it also converges in $C^{2+\alpha}$ space